# Toad ERX to Visio ER diagram convertion

Tags: database-design, oracle10g, visio, toad, erd

How to convert an ERX file that is generated from Oracle Toad that need to open via MS Visio for editing purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the Reverse Engineer option has been taken out of Visio 2013.  If you have a copy of 2010 you can still import erx files.

Comment: How do you import with Visio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bummer than you can't just import an ERX from Toad, but you can create one in Visio from the schema in Oracle:

1. In Visio, create a new database model diagram
2. In the Database tab on the ribbon, click the Reverse Engineer button
3. In the Reverse Engineer Wizard, in the Installed Visio drivers section, setup the oracle driver (for me, this consisted of just clicking the setup button and checking the box next to the only Oracle option present)
4. Create a new data source for the oracle driver (pretty self-explanatory there - service name, user id, etc)
5. Once the data source is created, next your way through picking which object types to include from which tables
6. On the last screen in this sequence, select the option "Yes, add the shapes to the current page" and it'll create your ER diagram

I had the same need - an ER diagram from Toad in Visio - and this worked nicely for me. I should note though that I'm not a database guy, so I kind of just muddled my way through this. I'm not sure if some of this was simpler for me because of my work environment, so your results may vary.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer to your question directly, but I think it can help other people looking to share the ERD created in TOAD without having to convert ERX files or anything.
Toad has the option to create an HTML report from the ERD, which shows the ERD and all relevant information in a good looking and very user friendly way.
To create such a report, click the world icon:
[World icon in Toad ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLm0g.png)

Afterwards you can select what you want to include in the report and the HTML is generated for you:
[HTML Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHJAl.png)